# Not enough space on my root

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

So I am trying to install and update some packages and for that I need some space (around 1 GB) in my root because every-time I open my Ubuntu I get a message that there is not enough space in your root. My gparted looks like this:

[image]

I am having a hard time understanding how can I increase my root space as I have much unallocated space in my drives.

I have already tried resizing2fs my /dev/sda5 but nothing worked. I got an output saying that "The filesystem is already 9301770 blocks long. Nothing to do".

What else can I do or how should I proceed ?

Comment: I don't understand where your problem is. /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda7 both are only slightly more than half used, and you only need to do some updates, yes?

Comment: Something does seem wonky here, gparted is showing you have plenty of space, but you are getting low space warning.  With your partition setup, resizing will not be easy.

Comment: The odd thing about your screenshot is that the root partition is not showing up. Have you got another drive somewhere?